# Why does toggling a Movieclip's visibility causes its child input TextField to not work properly in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript, textfield, visible

In Actionscript 3, I have functions that reveal or hide objects on the stage. However, some of these objects that call these functions have a TextField set to input, and when I try to select the text input, it won't let me after I call the function to turn its parent invisible (well, it does kind of, but I have to mash the keyboard a bunch of times before a character gets revealed and this nothing reliable). The code for these objects extends this:

public class MenuNavigation extends MovieClip 
    {

```
    public function MenuNavigation()  
    {
        // constructor code
    }
    public function RevealMenu():void
    {
        this.visible = true;
    }
    public function HideMenu():void
    {
        this.visible = false;
    }

}
```

I'm certain this is caused by toggling the .visible property to false, but I am at a loss on how to reactivate them or any alternates that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was able to achieve my goal by doing this:

```
    public function RevealMenu():void
    {
        this.alpha = 100;
        this.mouseChildren = true;
        this.enabled = true;
        this.mouseEnabled = true;
        //Makes things visible for MenuMain
    }
    public function HideMenu():void
    {
        this.alpha = 0;
        this.mouseChildren = false;
        this.enabled = false;
        this.mouseEnabled = false;
        //Hides the MenuMain
    }
```